# Is there any way to check many tags' popularity on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Say I want to compare two tags, like

`#Friday` `#Wednesday`

My attempt is to make a search and see how many tweets we got in the last 24 hours.

But this is very slow.

Is there any tool to check a lot of these tags?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHnrqczaVdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, but not always the best, would be to use the Twitter app for either iOS or Android. In either of those two Twitter apps, tap Search and type in your hashtag -- for example, `#friday`.

A list of approximate hashtags will be returned, with popularity numbers for each hashtag -- generally, "*x* Tweets today" or "*x* Tweets in the last hour."

As you can see in the image below, `#friday` is not as popular as other hashtags with the same first word, so its stats aren't shown. Stats for other, more popular hashtags *are* shown. For those hashtags, this technique will work.

[image]

To get the statistics for other hashtags, you'll probably need to use a third-party program or app. See the links below for lists of third-party tools (some paid, some free) that will display hashtag popularity stats.

- [15 free hashtag tracking tools - from the experts](https://www.talkwalker.com/blog/6-free-hashtag-tracking-tools-from-the-experts) (TalkWalker.com)
- [How to Find the Best Twitter Hashtags](https://sproutsocial.com/insights/twitter-hashtags/) (SproutSocial.com)
- [Which services track hashtag popularity over time?](https://www.quora.com/Which-services-track-hashtag-popularity-over-time) (Quora.com)